# Here Android SDK turn-to-turn voice instructions in text form

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using Here Android SDK and turn-to-turn voice instructions with pre-recorded voices. I want to duplicate voice commands at some visual ui, but in order to do that, I need to get the exact text, which voice engine speaks at exact time.

I can't use `NewInstructionEventListener` for that since I can parse it differently and it gives me only one instruction per turn (so I can't handle the situation "turn left after 150 m" > "turn left"). Is there any callback for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pre-recorded voices `NewInstructionEventListener` is the only option because it's simply a collection of audio files.
For TTS voices you can implement `AudioPlayerDelegate` and pass it to the `NavigationManager`. In this case, you will be able to receive an exact text that will be pronounced.
You can look at example https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/TtsAndNavigation.zip

Comment: its a collection of audio files, and messages _formed_ from it by some algorithm and for some data from NewInstructionEventListener. so it's technically possible...I only need to algorithm...for different missing data pieces at NewInstructionEventListener.

Comment: Maybe I described it incorrectly, but in the case of pre-recorded voices, there are no messages. Then you heard something like "After 100 meters turn right" it means that the whole phrase is recorded in advance. SDK just have a logic of then and how those pre-recorded audio files should be played.

Comment: oh, I see. I thought pre-recorded audio contain "After". Then all the meters separatelly. Then "turn right" \ "turn left" and so. And I thought that there is some output from selection model. Ok, I will try to implement it myself and check as many routes as I can, to confirm that my algorithm works as Here. If no - it will lead to difference between visual notifications and sound.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the creation of a final phrase from pieces of audio files.

Comment: BTW, Here support are absolutelly the best ever!) Thanks for all the effords from you and David Leong) This let developers to trackle issues faster)